# Use of colon or other options?

Tags: punctuation

A student had this sentence in her paper, and I think it is wrong:

> Breakfast or sleep: that is the question.

I think this would be correct:

> Breakfast or sleep? That is the question.

Are there any other options?

Comment: The colon use looks fine to me. The speaker is stating a choice, but is not really asking a question (in spite of the word "question" in the example). One doesn't need to precede each use of "That is the question" with an actual question. For example: "I haven't decided whether to go or stay. That is the question."

Comment: One could argue passionately whether to us a question mark, semi colon, or colon.  In my copy of Hamlet, a comma is used.  There are things which are definitely "right" or "wrong" and this is a grey area.  If you do some searching on the internet you will find dozens of authorities claiming what is right or wrong for punctuation in English.

Comment: According to Grammar Girl, a colon isn't the best choice here...http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/colons...so is "Breakfast or Sleep" a "true" sentence?

Answer (score 5):

Different versions (or discussions) of *Hamlet* provide multiple options for sentences structured like the one you present here. Here are 24 alternatives that the first 10 pages of a Google Books search for "to be or not to be that is the question" turned up.

From [*The Plays of William Shakespeare*](https://books.google.com/books?id=kAAOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA207&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirxMSNpLzJAhUDL4gKHUifAnQ4KBDoAQhEMAc#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22&f=false) (1765):

> *Hamlet.* To be, or not to be ? that is the question.--

From [*The Plays of William Shakspeare*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RjkUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA156&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22+Hamlet&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP796WmLzJAhWSKYgKHXpcCno4ChDoAQhRMAk#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22%20Hamlet&f=false) (1793):

> HAMLET. To be, or not to be, that is the question:—

From William Scott, [*Lessons in Elocution*](https://books.google.com/books?id=WlcCAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA334&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN84GGp7zJAhXLXIgKHRQoCHk4WhDoAQg-MAY#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22&f=false) (1823):

> To be—or not to be—that is the question ;

From Edward Bulwer Lytton, "[The Present Crisis: A Letter to a Late Cabinet Minister](https://books.google.com/books?id=nElBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA18&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim3P-oprzJAhXBMYgKHZ8yBXg4RhDoAQhMMAk#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22&f=false)" (1834):

> To be, or not to be—that is the question.

From [*Punch, or the London Charivari*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TEVIAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA66&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBxqrooLzJAhXWMYgKHWntC3Q4FBDoAQhHMAc#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22&f=false), (1843):

> To be, or not to be; that is the question.

From Goold Brown, [*The Grammar of English Grammars: With an Introduction, Historical and Critical*](https://books.google.com/books?id=q4gSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA799&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUy_HVm7zJAhXQT4gKHb2UA3s4ChDoAQgsMAM#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22&f=false) (1851), citing *Enfield's Sp.*, p. 367 & *Kirkham's Eloc.*, 123.:

> To be, or not to be?—that is the question.

From the same [citing *Singer's Shak.*, ii, 488]:

> To be or not to be, that is the question:

From the same [citing *Ward's Gram.*, p. 160]:

> To be, or not to be: that is the Question.

From the same [citing *Brightland's Gram.*, p. 209]:

> To be, or not to be, that is the Question:

From the same [citing *Pinneo's Gram.*, p. 176]:

> To be or not to be! That is the question.

From the same [citing *Burgh's Speaker*, p. 179]:

> To *be*—or *not* to *be*—*that* is the *question*.

From the same [the corrected form, according to Mr. Brown]:

> To be, or not to be;—that is the question.

From [*A New Variorum Edition of Shakespeare: Hamlet*](https://books.google.com/books?id=a5VHAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA205&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22+Hamlet&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP796WmLzJAhWSKYgKHXpcCno4ChDoAQhGMAc#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22%20Hamlet&f=false) (1877):

> *Hamlet*. To be or not to be,—that is the question;

From William Wright, "[Hamlet](https://books.google.com/books?id=AzIRAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA693&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22+Hamlet&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4psKQmLzJAhXCm4gKHR6VA3gQ6AEIPzAH#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22%20Hamlet&f=false)," in *The Atlantic Monthly* (1902):

> "To be or not to be," that is "the question."

From Xunwu Chen, [*Being and Authenticity*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3Uoey3HgqdIC&pg=PA1&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgoMvporzJAhVPUYgKHdKMBng4HhDoAQggMAE#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22&f=false) (2004):

> to be or not to be, that is the question!

From Allen Carlson, [*Aesthetics and the Environment: The Appreciation of Nature, Art and Architecture*](https://books.google.com/books?id=WdWFAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA199&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBxqrooLzJAhXWMYgKHWntC3Q4FBDoAQhMMAg#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22&f=false) (2005):

> To be, or not to be: that is the question.

From Judith Wright, [*The One Decision: Make the Single Choice That Will Lead to a Life of More*](https://books.google.com/books?id=dOqjOiQKh6kC&pg=PT24&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgoMvporzJAhVPUYgKHdKMBng4HhDoAQgwMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22&f=false) (2006):

> To be, or not to be. That is the question.

From John Rowell, [*To Give Or Not to Give?: Rethinking Dependency, Restoring Generosity, and Redefining Sustainability*](https://books.google.com/books?id=tVEUVp1H4hsC&pg=PA4&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUy_HVm7zJAhXQT4gKHb2UA3s4ChDoAQhDMAc#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22&f=false) (2009):

> To be, or not to be: that is the question:

From Nilton Bender, [*To Have or Not to Have That Is the Question: The Economics of Desire*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cZ1WAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT9&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcyZWWm7zJAhUQpYgKHToNAHcQ6AEIMzAF#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22&f=false) (2010):

> To be or not to be? That is the question!

From Lisa Nielsen & Willyn Webb, [*Teaching Generation Text: Using Cell Phones to Enhance Learning*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_US096G6C_kC&pg=PA174&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBxqrooLzJAhXWMYgKHWntC3Q4FBDoAQggMAE#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22&f=false) (2011):

> To be or not to be, that is the question?

From Esther Rashkin, [*Family Secrets and the Psychoanalysis of Narrative*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qjkABAAAQBAJ&pg=PA42&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi82vjGpbzJAhWLTYgKHZ1-Cns4PBDoAQgxMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22&f=false) (2014):

> “To be or not to be"—that *is* the question for Hamlet.

From P.I. Sabbathi, [*Soulzer: Be a Spiritual-Soldier to Undergird Your Own Soul*](https://books.google.com/books?id=wGh1AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA114&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirxMSNpLzJAhUDL4gKHUifAnQ4KBDoAQgnMAI#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22&f=false) (2014):

> To be or not to be... that is the question.

From Michael Rothan, [*"61 Minutes": Reflections and Homilies for the Year of Matthew*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JbeFAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA67&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjguL-FpbzJAhXBV4gKHRKZBHo4MhDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22&f=false) (2014):

> *to be or not to be* (that is the question?)

From Dympna Callaghan, [*Hamlet: Language and Writing*](https://books.google.com/books?id=KAJxBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA34&dq=%22to+be+or+not+to+be+that+is+the+question%22+Hamlet&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP796WmLzJAhWSKYgKHXpcCno4ChDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20or%20not%20to%20be%20that%20is%20the%20question%22%20Hamlet&f=false) (2015):

> To be, or not to be — that is the question.

Not all of these formulations are especially good. In particular, the ones suggested by Nielsen & Webb (2011) and Rothan (2014) verge on the ridiculous. But most of the others are coherent enough, and they show considerable range in the punctuation they use to separate the two main phrases of the quotation—comma, semicolon, colon, period, em dash, ellipsis points, question mark, and exclamation point, with quotation marks as another variable.

My preference matches Ricky's, as given in a separate answer: I like the colon or the em dash for separation of the first phrase from the second. But the question mark approach that you prefer isn't wrong, and neither (in my view) are the period, the exclamation point, the comma (despite its seeming to approach a comma splice), and even the semicolon and the ellipsis points.

Each form of punctuation alters the tone or mood or tendency of the quotation slightly, so it's important to choose your weapons with care. But again, any of a number of possibilities may be valid in a particular context.

Comment: +1. There's more to say about the options though. For instance, sandwiching "not to be" between dashes renders it subordinate with respect to "to be", which misinterprets the intended meaning of the sentence. One must remain true to the author's intention.

Comment: @Fard: You're right that some of the forms of punctuation shown above substantially subvert Shakespeare's probable intention. A colleague of mine (a copy editor) said that her number one rule in editing another person's work was "First do no harm." It's as valid in editing as in medicine, I think.

Comment: Good answer...I never knew there were that many ways to punctuate this.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct.

It is a lame parody of the first line of Hamlet's soliloquy in Act III. To be perfectly fair, the punctuation has varied in it over the past 400 years. Today, there are two ways to punctuate it:

**To be, or not to be: that is the question:**

Or -

**To be, or not to be--that is the question:**

That comma after "be," indicating the pause between stating the second choice, would not look right in the student's sentence, since two nouns, rather than two verbs, represent the choices.

To summarize:

**Breakfast or sleep: that is the question.**

That is the correct way to pucntuate it.

Comment: Seems a little shaky, Ricky.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Let me be, I'm drunk. How's that literature site going?

Comment: There is something particularly shaky about (a) two colons in the one line, and (b) the use of an em dash in lieu of the first colon. I agree with the comma after *To be*, of course. And the answer is rescued with (by) the correct (minimalist) punctuation for the OP line — **Breakfast or sleep: that is the question.**

Comment: You're probably right about the two colons, but, hey, blame Shakespeare's editors. I didn't make it up. I truly resent em-dashes, and try to avoid them wherever possible, but the way the metaphor (in poetry) is the default figure of speech, so is the em-dash the default punctuation mark. Byron used nothing else, and then asked his friends to "point" his work. The OP's line doesn't scan.

Comment: I don't agree with the comma after the first "be." Hamlet is deciding between two distinct paths. It is the equivalent of saying __Cookies or ice cream--that is the question.__ (I like the em-dash in the author's example.) The spoken pause does not need a comma in prose/narrative. If a long pause is added stylistically, the dude is considering suicide after all, then I think an ellipses is most appropriate.